# Impedance Matching Necessary for short HDMI trace?

Tags: transmission-line, impedance-matching, hdmi

So, I am working on a design that uses HDMI for media output. The PCB has a connector for the Raspberry Pi CM4, and usually what I would do, is to do a "differential pair route" where I do a quick online calculation to check the differential impedance, and then route to the connector. But, with this design, I have the opportunity to place the HDMI right at the CM4 connector, literally 2.5mm away. This messes with the differential router tool that I normally would use. But, with the traces being so short, is impedance matching even necessary? At what rise time frequency does HDMI operate? I would definitely think impedance matching is required when we have traces longer than 5mm, but in this case it feels unnecessary.[image: Do short HDMI traces require impedance matching?]

Comment: For 2 millimeter it shouldn't really matter unless you are *really* out of tolerance. A good ground plane is vital however

Comment: Do you need to pass official HDMI testing (i.e. are you going to sell that device)? What resolutions/bandwidth/pixelclocks/TMDSclocks are you going to use?

Comment: I am learning all the more that a good ground plane is vital... And, no we aren't planning for official HDMI testing. As I also understand, the CM4 is HDMI compliant? Would that cover the carrier board, or would the carrier again be sent in for compliance testing (should we want that)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impedance match is affected somewhat in the unequal line length skew of differential pulses and mismatched impedance with 3mm on a 2GHz signal.  Usually it affects a few dynamic pixels when other noise is present such as CM ground noise from SMPS.

Below is shown for 50 to 120 ohm 3mm stripline @ 2Ghz .  It depends on your resolution , signal rate and CMRR of balun.  But path time delays < 10% of a wavelength is a safe limit.

[image]